# How to create a BlocListener that can listen to all pages in flutter with access to MaterialApp context?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, bloc

I'm trying to create a `BlocListener` that has the ability to listen to all pages/routes throughout the app just like how you can access a `Bloc` or a `Provider` all throughout the app if they are defined at root-level like in the code below

```
runApp(
  MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<IdentityTokenProvider>(
        create: (_) => IdentityTokenProvider(),
      ),
    ],
    child: MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
          create: (_) => AuthBloc(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: AppConfig.DEBUGGABLE,
        theme: ThemeData(
            // fontFamily: CustomFontStyle.montserrat,
            ),
        home: AuthListener(
          child: Center(
            child: const MainApp(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

As you can see, I have providers, blocs, and one listener. I have no problem accessing the blocs and providers in other pages. My problem is the auth listener. I lose access to the `AuthListener` once I move to a different page (by removing stack) , because it is inside the `MaterialApp`. However, in this instance, I need that specific listener (`AuthListener`) to be inside a `MaterialApp`, because it consists of code that uses page navigations (which doesn't work if the implementation is done outside/above the widget tree of a `MaterialApp`), and makes us of the `MaterialApp` context for showing dialogs.

My implementation of page routing which removes the stack, which is another cause of losing access to the `AuthListener`

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => route),
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Why do I remove the route/page stack when moving to a different page?

- I specifically use this after authentication. You don't really want a user to be able to press back button after logging in, andredirect the user back to the login page right? Usually back button should hide/close the app when they are logged in.

My `AuthListener` implementation

```
class AuthListener extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const AuthListener({Key key, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthListenerState createState() => _AuthListenerState();
}

class _AuthListenerState extends State<AuthListener> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthAuthenticated) {
          PageRouterController.pushAndRemoveStack(context, const EcomPage());
        } else if (state is AuthUnauthenticated) {
          PageRouterController.pushAndRemoveStack(context, const LoginPage());
        }
      },
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a different way around this?

Comment: did you try wrapping the listener with a  Builder widget?

Comment: What's the purpose of using a builder widget? Isn't that a widget where you could just add some code and then return a widget?

Comment: if I understand your problem is that you can't listen to AuthBloc because it is at the same level in the tree as the AuthBloc right?

Comment: From my understanding as well, is that I can't access the AuthBloc (once I have finished authentication and moved to a different page), because the listener is in the MaterialApp. From my understand, I can only access root-level blocs, providers, listeners (which are defined above the MaterialApp). Which means I have access to the AuthListener at login page, but when I move to a different page. I lose access to it.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this btw, because I'm planning to create a functionality which force logs out a user when the user receives a silent notification via FCM(payload only). So I need the AuthListener to be inside the MaterialApp because I need its context to be able to change routes/pages via MaterialPageRoute, as well as showing dialogs. But then, the issue arises where I can't access it at different pages because it has to be at root-level to be accessible everywhere.

Comment: If you need to access a bloc provided at the same level in a material app you need to wrap the bloc listener (which in turn is the home of the material app) with a Builder widget which in its builder property takes a builder and gives you a context that has the above Bloc available to use
this is what I understand your problem is

Comment: Can I get an example code (it can be minimal) of what you're trying to show? Btw, all of my code works. It's just the losing access part, that I'm having a problem with. I added the code of my AuthListener in the post btw.

Comment: return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => getIt<ThemeBloc>(),
        )
      ],
      child: Builder(
        builder: (_) => BlocBuilder<ThemeBloc, ThemeState>(
          builder: (_, state) => MaterialApp(
            home:BlocListener<ThemeBloc>(
              listener: (ctx,state){
                //todo
              },
              child: (ctx,state){//this ctx can reach the ThemeBloc
                return someChild();
              },
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Comment: Isn't this the same as mine? I don't have an issue accessing the material app context really. What I'm saying is, I can't move it at root-level because I would otherwise lose access to the MaterialApp context which I need. But then, not placing it at root-level, makes me lose access to it when I move to a different page because AuthListener is not at root-level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211973/discussion-between-user-and-rick).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I ended up defining a

```
static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey();
```

and used it in my MaterialApp

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: App.DEBUGGABLE,
      theme: ThemeData(
          // fontFamily: CustomFontStyle.montserrat,
          ),
      navigatorKey: App.navigatorKey,
      home: Center(
        child: const LoginPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So then, whenever I have to navigate in cases where the implementation is outside the MaterialApp (in my case via the AuthListener which is found at root-level, above the MaterialApp), I can navigate via

```
App.navigatorKey.currentState.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => route),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Which means I can finally have access to the MaterialApp navigator and context even with the listener outside the MaterialApp which allows me to do both navigation and showing of dialogs